# MultiBinding DataTemplate for ListView.ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, datatemplate, itemtemplate, multibinding

I just wanted to define a custom `DataTemplate` for my `ListView` in order to show some data of a class.
In an earlier project (c#, .net 3.5, wpf) I had something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Custom_ComboBox_Style" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}    {1} Members">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="MemberCount"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my current WinRT project :(
I searched google and found out that WinRT has no `MultiBinding` anymore.
I couldn't find any solution to this problem until now.
Any idea(s) how to solve this and achieve a similiar `DataTemplate` like the one above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MemberCount}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Members"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```